# Implicit Euler Scheme and stability

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Find the fixed points of the implicit Euler scheme
\begin{equation} y_{n+1}-y_{n}= hf(t_{n+1},y_{n+1})
\end{equation}
when applied to the differential equation $y'=y(1-y)$ and investigate their stability?

=>
implicit Euler scheme
\begin{equation} y_{n+1}-y_{n}= hf(t_{n+1},y_{n+1})
\end{equation}

$y'=y(1-y)$
\begin{equation} y_{n+1}=y_{n}+hy_{n+1}(1-y_{n+1})
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} y_{n+1}=y_{n}+hy_{n+1}-hy^2_{n+1}
\end{equation}

For fixed points
$y_{n+1}=y_{n}$
\begin{equation} y_{n}=y_{n}+hy_{n}-hy^2_{n}
\end{equation}
$y_{n}=0$ or $1$

I got problem with stability but this is what I have done

$y_{n}= \alpha +\epsilon^n$,  $y_{n+1}= \alpha +\epsilon^{n+1}$,
\begin{equation} \alpha +\epsilon^{n+1}= \alpha +\epsilon^n + h (\alpha +\epsilon^{n+1})(1-\alpha -\epsilon^{n+1}) \end{equation}
\begin{equation} \epsilon^{n+1}= \epsilon^n + h (\alpha +\epsilon^{n+1})(1-\alpha -\epsilon^{n+1}) \end{equation}
When $y_{n}=0=\alpha$
\begin{equation} \epsilon^{n+1}= \epsilon^n + h \epsilon^{n+1}(1-\epsilon^{n+1}) \end{equation}

I don't what to say or do after that to determine the stability.

When $y_{n}=1=\alpha$
\begin{equation} \epsilon^{n+1}= \epsilon^n - h \epsilon^{n+1}(1+\epsilon^{n+1}) \end{equation}

same again what can say about with my answer to investigate the stability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from
$$
y_{n+1}=y_{n}+hy_{n+1}(1-y_{n+1})
$$
multiply with $4h$ and rearrange
$$
(2hy_{n+1})^2+2(2hy_{n+1})(1-h)=4hy_n
\\
(2hy_{n+1}+(1-h))^2=(1-h)^2+4hy_n
$$
to get
\begin{align}
y_{n+1}&=\frac1{2h}\left(-(1-h)+\sqrt{(1-h)^2+4hy_n}\right)
\\
&=1+\frac1{2h}\left(-(1+h)+\sqrt{(1+h)^2-4h+4hy_n}\right)
\\[0.8em]
&=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{2y_n}{(1-h)+\sqrt{(1-h)^2+4hy_n}}
&\approx \dfrac{y_n}{1-h}
&&\text{ for } y_n\approx 0
\\[0.3em]
1+\dfrac{2(y_n-1)}{(1+h)+\sqrt{(1+h)^2+4h(y_n-1)}}
&\approx 1+\dfrac{y_n-1}{1+h}
&&\text{ for } y_n\approx 1
\end{cases}
\end{align}
In this direct form, the reasoning about stability should be a little easier.

---

Or even more directly: Stability analysis is about the linearization, so just remove the term that are quadratic in $ϵ^{n+1}$ to get magnification factors of $(1-h)^{-1}$ and $(1+h)^{-1}$, indicating one stable and one unstable solution.

Comment: How can I remove the term that are in quadratic. would you please show me what you really mean?

Comment: That is what "linearization" means, you disregard the higher order terms as negligible. The idea is that the initial perturbation is infinitesimal and that squares of infinitesimals, even summed up in finitely many steps, are still much smaller than the linear terms.